# Android FacebookSDK 3.0.b getAttributionId always returns null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am attempting to setup one of our titles to use the latest Facebook SDK. The primary function of interest is Settings.getAttributionId (formerly Facebook.getAttributionId) however when I call this function it always returns null.

I have installed the facebook.apk that comes with facebook and signed in without any luck.

In LogCat I did notice this error shortly after the query:
11-02 22:26:01.522: E/ActivityThread(25521): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

Just curious if anyone has ideas what would cause this, or what I may have set wrong (or not set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a very recent build of the Facebook for Android application on the device for this to work.  I have not checked, but the version included in the sdk beta download may be too old to support this.  If you try it on a real device where you have installed the latest Facebook application from the Play Store this should work.

Comment: That was the problem. Just downloaded latest app and I am getting the attribution id. Thank you!